# can't detect object model

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, i made 3D object model with roboearth stack like in this tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth/Tutorials/Record%20an%20object%20model

when i tried to detect this object using

```
rosrun re_kinect_object_detector re_kinect
```

and

```
rosrun re_object_detector_gui detect
```

it begin to read the model then received cloud points and open the detect gui

but No detection happened!
No error just receiving point clouds for a long time !!
No red mask on the object like in this picture :

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49058/can%27t-detect-object-model/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-25**:
@ddimarco :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that the camera is ~60 cm away from the object, from your screenshot it looks a bit too close.
To get some visual debug information, you can uncomment the "#define DEBUG_VIS" line in re_kinect_object_detector/src/recognitionmodel.h. This will show you the images from the model, the SURF features and possible matches from the model as lines.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-26**:
I have uncommented the "#define DEBUG_VIS" line in re_kinect_object_detector/src/recognitionmodel.h.   and the camera now is 60 cm away from the object, but still have the same problem .

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2012-11-26**:
DEBUG_VIS does not really change anything, it is just there to help you find problems. Please note that we use 2D features only, so maybe the coke bottle does not provide enough features. What happens if you try it with another, more textured object?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-26**:
I already have tried my own object model but no detection occurred ,so i have downloaded the object model of the coke bottle from roboearth.org but the kinect didn't detect it too ,so i think that the problem isn't with the object model and i can't find object models of products in egypt

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2012-11-26**:
Ok, it is hard to figure out the problem like this. Well textured objects like the one at http://api.roboearth.org/data/objects/beverage/icetea/preview.png should work very well. So all advice I can offer is to record an object model for something like that and try it again.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-27**:
@ddimarco thanks alot it works ! ,, but i would ask about objects that have One color or little textured
How can i detect it ? ? and i thought that cloud points features are width and height and color
but it detected a similar object Not exactly it !!?

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2012-11-27**:
As I said, the software only uses 2D image features. You'll need to use another package if you require to  detect single-colored objects.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-27**:
Ok ,, thanks :)